# How can a munge method of a Puppet custom type access an entire array parameter?

Tags: puppet

This property is an array, whose order does not matter. It's really a set, but Puppet doesn't have sets AFAICT. So I'm trying to use `munge` to sort the values:

```
newproperty(:things, :array_matching => :all) do  
  munge do |value|
    value.sort
  end
end
```

This fails, because the `munge` is applied to each of the values in the array instead of the whole thing. Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and resolved it [like this:](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-iis/pull/252)

```
newproperty(:things, :array_matching => :all) do  
  def should(values)
    sort(super)
  end
  def should=(values)
    super
    sort!(@should)
  end
  def insync?(is)
    sort(is) == should
  end
end
```

If I were writing a new module, I'd use the [Resources API](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/create_types_and_providers_resource_api.html), which has a [canonicalize](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/about_the_resource_api.html#canonicalize) hook for this very purpose.

Comment: Thanks for this! Unfortunately I no longer have a way to test it, having moved on from that project, so it may be a while before I can try it out. If we're lucky, perhaps someone else will!